# Como posso remover a primeira coluna de numeros pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Alguem me pode dizer como eu posso remover a primeira coluna do `output` do pandas e a pimeira coluna?

**Imagem do que eu quero remover:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Meu CSV:**

Link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16mDhKkVIqzS43SDUd6BAHDP6ZUUoeu52/view?usp=sharing

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Meu codigo:**

```
import pandas
import os

FileName = 'AiroDumpOutPut'
FileNameCSV = f'{FileName}-01.csv'
Directory = 'Data/Aircrack-ng/'
ExplorePath = os.path.isfile(f'{Directory}{FileNameCSV}')

def OS():
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')

def Explorer(interface):
    if ExplorePath == True:
        OS()
        os.remove(f'{Directory}{FileNameCSV}')
        os.system(f"sudo airodump-ng -w {Directory}{FileName} --output-format csv {interface}")
        return Decoder()
    else:
        OS()
        os.system(f"sudo airodump-ng -w {Directory}{FileName} --output-format csv {interface}")
        return Decoder()

def Decoder():

    global bssid
    global channel
    global essid
    global encrypt

    CS = pandas.read_csv(f'{Directory}{FileNameCSV}')
    stop_row = CS[CS.BSSID == 'Station MAC'].index[0] -1

    OS()
    df = pandas.read_csv(f'{Directory}{FileNameCSV}', nrows = stop_row)
    df = df.drop(df.columns[[1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14]], axis=1)
    print(df)
    print()
    ColectedInput = int(input("Please enter the number of the network: "))

    number = 0
    while number < 100:
        if ColectedInput == number:
            #GET THE SELECTED ROW
            out = pandas.read_csv(f'{Directory}{FileNameCSV}', nrows = stop_row)
            out = out.drop(out.columns[[1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14]], axis=1)
            out = out.iloc[[number]]
            #GET BSSID
            bssid = pandas.read_csv(f'{Directory}{FileNameCSV}', nrows = stop_row)
            bssid = bssid.drop(bssid.columns[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]], axis=1)
            bssid = bssid.iloc[[number]]

            OS()
            print(out)
            print()
            print(f'BSSID: {bssid}')
            #print(f'Channel: {channel}')
            #print(f'ESSID: {essid}')
            #print(f'Encryption: {encrypt}')
        number = number + 1
```

Basicamente o que eu preciso e de remover a `coluna` com o numero que a identifica e a `linha` que diz `BSSID`

**Espero ter esclarecido o meu problema!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No `print(out)` você pode usar

```
print(out.to_string(index=False, header=False))
```

Lembrando que isso não remove essas informações que fazem parte do seu DataFrame. Apenas não exibe no print.

Mais informações aqui: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_string